# Function with @jit(nopython=True) decorator only produces the correct result if contains a print statement within it

Tags: python, numpy, numba, jit

I am speeding up computation for a function with a loop using numba.njit compiler. But I see that if I use the function with @njit and a print statement inside, or without the decorator (no need of the print statement) I obtain the correct answer, but if the function has the decorator with the print statement commented out, then the answer is incorrect (I checked the answer but calculating outside the function and it outputs what is expected).

The code starts with:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

P, A, G = 1/2.22, 0.3, 2.
T_grid = np.linspace(1e-10, 1, 101)
z_grid = np.array([0.98306027, 0.98474125, 0.98642511, 0.98811184, 0.98980146, 0.99005298])
```

which is common to all parts. Then, I implement the following function (which I need to use to calculate several states, therefore the need to make it fast):

```
@njit
def initial_guesses(P, A, G, T_grid, z_grid, T_idx=16):

    # set fixed values for the loop
    z_grid_size = len(z_grid)
    T = T_grid[T_idx]

    # initialize vector to store calculated values
    v = -1e10 * np.ones((z_grid_size))

    for z_idx in range(z_grid_size):
        l = (z_grid[z_idx] / (1. + T))**(1. / P)
        c = (z_grid[z_idx] / (1. + T))**((1. + P) / P)
        g = T * c
        if (g >= 1e-10) and (c - (l**(1. + P))/(1. + P) >= 1e-10):
            u = A * (g**(1. - G) / (1. - G)) + \
                    (1. - A) * ((c - ((l**(1. + P)) / (1. + P)))**(1. - G) / (1. - G))
#           print(np.maximum(v[z_idx], u))
            v[z_idx] = np.maximum(v[z_idx], u)
    return v
```

When I run it with the print statement commented out, the output is:

```
array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.])
```

However, when the print statement is read by the code the output is the expected one:

```
array([-7.03544442, -6.99684645, -6.95846025, -6.92028464, -6.88231847,
       -6.87669001])
```

Which I compared by running the following code:

```
z_grid_size = len(z_grid)
T = T_grid[16]
v_2 = -1e10 * np.ones(z_grid_size)
for z_idx in range(z_grid_size):
    l = (z_grid[z_idx] / (1. + T))**(1. / P)
    c = (z_grid[z_idx] / (1. + T))**((1. + P) / P)
    g = T * c
    if (g >= 1e-10) and (c - (l**(1. + P))/(1. + P) >= 1e-10):
        u = A * (g**(1. - G) / (1. - G)) + \
            (1. - A) * ((c - ((l**(1. + P)) / (1. + P)))**(1. - G) / (1. - G))
        v_2[z_idx] = np.maximum(v_2[z_idx], u)
print(v_2)
```

that produces the same output as the one from the jitted function with the print statement, or the function without the decorator. Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What is `u_d`? It doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: The code contains an invalid `import`, no output or return after commenting the `print` line and undefined variables. Please don't use greak variable names (they are very hard to type) and provide a [mre].

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I've edited the code to account for the mistakes, and it's now reproducible.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem on my machine (Numba 0.55.2). Can you specify the version of Numba you use and try the latest version (Numba is actively developed and quite young so bug like this are not so rare in early versions but quickly fixed).

Comment: @JérômeRichard I had Numba 0.55.1. I updated to 0.55.2 but the issue remains.